# Trouble with Relationship content displaying

Tags: relationships

Following a recent upgrade to EE 2.6.1 I am having trouble with relationship navigation content showing up correctly [here](http://hpgresources.com/customer-services/services-overview). The content in question is the right sidebar where is says: Sub Navigation.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Subnavs -->                                                         
                        <div class="box"> 
                            <h2>Sub Navigation</h2>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                {exp:channel:entries channel="customer_services" orderby="entry_date" dynamic="off" sort="asc"}
                                {if parent_page=="0"}                   
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{title_permalink=customer-services}" title="{title}">{title}</a>
                                        {reverse_related_entries weblog="customer_services"}
                                            {if count==1}<ul>{/if}
                                            <li><a href="{title_permalink=customer-services}" title="{title}">{title}</a></li>
                                            {if count==total_results}</ul>{/if}
                                        {/reverse_related_entries}
                                    </li>
                                {/if}
                                {/exp:channel:entries} 
                            </ul> 
                        </div>
```

I would appreciate any guidance for getting this to display correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Relationships were completely rewritten in EE 2.6, so your reverse_related_entries will no longer work unfortunately.

See http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#tag-reference for updated documentation.

However the updater should have replaced your existing relationship tags with their equivalents.

Comment: The upgrade did not change it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `reverse_reated_entries`, use the `parents` tag in 2.6. (Also, you're using `weblog` when you should be using `channel`).

```
{parents channel="customer_services" field="relationship_field_name"}
    {if parents:count == "1"}<ul>{/if}
    <li><a href="{parents:title_permalink="customer-services/index"}" title="{parents:title}">{parents:title}</a></li>
    {if parents:count == parents:total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/parents}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, I see the logic in the code you provided, however, when I implement it I get four different PHP errors related to: Undefined offset: 52, Filename: relationship_parser/Parser.php;

Comment: Perhaps you don't need the `parents:` prefix to the `title_permalink` tag. Try removing that.

Comment: Hi Derek, I still get the same error.

Comment: You mention four errors - do you have four entries?

Comment: There are only three entries in the section that have relationships.

Comment: The `field` parameter is also required on the `parents:` tag - answer revised above.